# Jmeter XPATH get default value when node is not present

Tags: xpath, jmeter

```
<ST>
    <S a="54" r="2" t="12" />
    <S a="53" t="14" />
    <S a="52" r="12" t="14" />
</ST>
```

I would like to receive default value of r ("0") when it not present.
I have read solutions over here, but did not find suitable for my specific needs:

defined in Jmeter XPATH extractor
name of created variable: reps
xpath query: //ST/S/@r
default value 0
match : -1

expected vars in JMeter:
reps_1:2
reps_2:0
reps_3:12
actual:
reps_1:2
reps_2:12

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be switching to [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) (available since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)), the relevant query would be something like:

```
/*/*/(string(@r)[.], 0)[1]
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, indeed I was trying with XPATH ,which is not working with your solution , but with XPATH2 it works perfectly.
My solution for XPATH was /ST/S/@r | /ST/S[not (@r)] , which fill the array with null values for not existing @r